# Perl reading file, printing unique value from a column

Tags: arrays, perl, file, unique

I am new to perl, and i'd like to achieve the following with perl.

I have a file which contain the following data:

> ```
> /dev/hda1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0
> /dev/hda1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0
> ```

I'd like to extract the second field from the file and print unique values only. My desired output for this example is, the program should print :

`ext3`

also if i have several different filesystem, it should print in on the same line.

I have tried many piece of code but am left stuck.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %hash ;
while (<>) {
if (/\s*[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+\s+([^\s]+)\s+.*/) {
    $hash{$1}=1;
}
}
print join("\n",keys(%hash))."\n";
```

Usage:

```
 ./<prog-name>.pl file1 fil2 ....
```

Comment: can you please advise how do i use the file1 only? i.e i want to use only the first argument

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer `awk`:

```
$ cat file
/dev/hda1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0
/dev/hda1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0

$ awk '!seen[$3]++{print $3}' file
ext3
```

OR , using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d" " -f3 file  | sort | uniq      # or use just sort -u if your version supports it
ext3
```

Here is `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[2] unless $seen{$F[2]}++' file
ext3
```

Here is the perl command line options explanation (from `perl -h`):

```
l: enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
a: autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)
n: assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
e: one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

For a better explanation around these option, please refer: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of

Comment: It might be worth explaining your choice of flags as the OP is new to Perl.

Comment: @jaypal, Thanks. I wasn't aware that this can be done purely in `awk`.

Comment: @TomFenech, Added the explanation. Thanks.

Comment: thank, how do i print all the data on the same line separated with space?

Comment: @Shann, provide sample input and expected output for this new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -anE '$s{$F[2]}++ }{say for keys %s' file
```

or

```
perl -anE '$s{$_}++ or say for $F[2]' file
```

Comment: is is possible to write something like this in a perl script?
Which will use my first argument only as filename

Comment: @Shann yes, `perl -anE 'BEGIN{ @r= splice(@ARGV,1,$#ARGV) } $s{$_}++ or say for $F[2]' file`